# Parallelogram diagonals angles proof

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

Given: Parallelogram $ABCD$, $AC$=$\sqrt{2}AB$

Prove: Angle ABD = Angle DAC

[image: Proof diagram]

So far, I showed the following:

$\triangle DCA\sim\triangle BAC$ and $\triangle DOC\sim\triangle BOA$

DC = AB; DA = BC

$\angle D$ = $\angle B$, $\angle A$ = $\angle C$

$\angle CDB = \angle DBA$; $\angle ADB = \angle CBD$

How would I go on to prove it?

Comment: Sure? It seems not true.

Comment: You don't need to write ∆$DCA$~∆$BAC$; you can write $\triangle DCA\sim\triangle BAC$. I changed that. One can also write $\angle CDB$, etc. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this well know identity [Parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law)
$$2(AB^2+AD^2)=AC^2+BD^2$$
since
$$AC=\sqrt{2}AB\Longrightarrow BD=\sqrt{2}AD$$
let
$$AB=x,AD=y$$
then we have
$$\cos{\angle ABD}=\dfrac{AB^2+BD^2-AD^2}{2AB\cdot BD}=\dfrac{x^2+2y^2-y^2}{2x\sqrt{2}y}=\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{2\sqrt{2}xy}$$
and
$$\cos{\angle DAC}=\dfrac{AD^2+AC^2-DC^2}{2AD\cdot AC}=\dfrac{y^2+2x^2-x^2}{2y\sqrt{2}x}=\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{2\sqrt{2}xy}$$
so
$$\angle ABD=\angle DAC$$